# Finding upper and lower bounds of the harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, logarithms

I want to prove that, for any $n \in \mathbb {Z}^+$, $$\ln(n + 1) \leq 1 + \frac 1 2 + ... + \frac 1 n \leq 1 + \ln n\ ,$$ using the fact that, for any $i \in \mathbb {Z}^+$, $$\frac 1 {i + 1} \leq \ln(i + 1) - \ln i \leq \frac 1 i\ .$$

---

**Some background**

I am taking an introductory module to calculus in my university and this is actually one of the questions of my homework for this week. There are two parts to the question and this is the second part, which I have been stuck at for hours. The first part required me to prove that $$\frac 1 {i + 1} \leq \ln(i + 1) - \ln i \leq \frac 1 i\ ,$$ which I have finally been able to do. However, I am not getting any inspiration as to how I can use this to prove that $$\ln(n + 1) \leq 1 + \frac 1 2 + ... + \frac 1 n \leq 1 + \ln n\ .$$

I did a little research online about the middle portion of the inequality and found that it is a special series called the harmonic series (no series are taught in my module). The Wikipedia page on the harmonic series also showed how to prove the lower and upper bounds that I am looking for, but they are far beyond my current ability.

Any intuitions/suggestions on how to carry on this problem will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Here's a hint: Read about telescoping series and then try showing the inequality for low values of n. I wouldn't worry about the harmonic series aspect to it at the moment.

Comment: @Mathstudent1996 Oh thank you so much for the hint. I was still stuck on how to use the concepts of telescoping series but the answer provided made things more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, you in fact have two inequalities:
\begin{align}
\forall i \geqslant 1,~ \dfrac{1}{i+1} &\leqslant \ln(i+1) - \ln i &\text{and}~ \forall i \geqslant 1,~ \ln(i+1) - \ln i &\leqslant \dfrac{1}{i}
\end{align}
Sum the first for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, you find $\frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} \leqslant \ln n$. Add $1$ to both sides and you have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \leqslant \ln n +1
\end{align}

Sum the second inequality for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and you have
\begin{align}
\ln( n+1 ) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh my god. You are a genius. How... Thank you so much for the intuition.

Comment: @EthanMark Thanks, but it is not a genius thing, just a classical exercice!

Comment: Hello! I believe I found a mistake in your answer! The last line should be $\ln (n + 1) \leq \ ...$ instead of $\ln n \leq \ ...$ I thought to edit your answer directly but I felt you should be the one to do it :)

Comment: @EthanMark Yes there was this typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\tag 1\ln (n+1) = \int_1^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t} = \int_1^{2}\frac{dt}{t} + \int_2^{3}\frac{dt}{t} + \cdots +\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t}.$$

Take the first integral on the right of $(1).$ On the interval $[1,2],1/t\le 1.$ Thus

$$\int_1^{2}\frac{dt}{t} \le 1\cdot 1 = 1.$$

The same thing works for the second integral in the sum:

$$\int_2^{3}\frac{dt}{t} \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Continue to see that the sum on the right of $(1)$ is bounded above by

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I accepted the other one because it came first and I felt that was more intuitive (it came more naturally to me), but yours allows me to view the problem in another light, so I gave it an upvote too :)